# Physical Meaning of Probability Density "Current"

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Assume we have a current density vector, $\vec{J}$,
$$\vec{J}=P_r\ \vec{u} \tag{1}$$
Where $P_r$ is the probably of an $NVT$ macrostate with energy, $E_r$, and $\vec{u}$ is the phase-space velocity vector.

If we treat $\vec{J}$ as a conserved current we are able to obtain the results of Liouville's Theorem, namely,
$$div(\vec{J})+\frac{\partial P_r}{\partial t}=0 \tag{2}$$
Where the divergence operator includes $\{p_1,q_1,...\}$.
Or as a Poisson bracket,
$$\{H,p\}+\frac{\partial P_r}{\partial t}=0 \tag{3}$$
This works out quite nicely because we get the following:
$$div(\vec{J}) = \sum\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}(P_r \dot{q_i}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}(P_r \dot{p_i}) \tag{4}$$
With one part of the product rule of (4) leading to (3) and the other part yielding:
$$P_r \sum\frac{\partial \dot{q_i}}{\partial q_i} + \frac{\partial \dot{p_i}}{\partial p_i} = P_r \sum\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial q_i \partial p_i} - \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial p_i \partial q_i} =0 \tag{5}$$
(5) supports the argument that (1) makes physical sense since it shows that:
$$div(\vec{u})=0 \tag{6}$$
Leading to the widely discussed result that the phase space acts as an incompressible fluid.

### Questions

1. (1) implies the existence of some type of rate equation anagalous to mass or charge, e.g.,
   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} m= -\oint_S \vec{J_m} \cdot \vec{dS} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_V \rho_m\ dV \tag{7}$$
   What  would the $m$ (mass) be in the context of Liouville's Theorem, given that $\rho_m$ (mass per unit volume) corresponds to $P_r$?
2. Since $P_r$ is unitless, does this convolute the notion that $\vec{J}$ in (1) is physically a current density? Maybe this is just a mathematical nicety?